# How to calculate periods since 200-period high of a stock

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

I would like to calculate the number of periods that have elapsed since the 200 period high of a univariate time series.  For example, here's the closing price of SPY:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY",from='01-01-1900')
Data <- Cl(SPY)
```

Now, I can find the 200-period highs of this series using the `Lag` function in quantmod:

```
periodHigh <- function(x,n) {
    Lags <- Lag(x,1:n)
    High <- x == apply(Lags,1,max)
    x[High]
}
periodHigh(Data, 200)
```

But now I'm stuck.  How do I merge this back onto the original series (`Data`) and calculate, for each point in the series, how many periods have elapsed since the previous n-period high?

Comment: Let's say I had some sample data to work with...

Comment: And how do you define a 200 day high?  A day where the price is higher than on any of the preceding 200 days?

Comment: Business days or calendar days? And if business, then which financial center?

Comment: One more question:  For your sample data, what is the correct answer, i.e. the expected result?

Comment: @Dwin:  Let's simplify things, and say we're working with a univariate time series, with one observation per business day.  We want to calculate the number of periods that have elapsed since the previous 200 period high.  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Andrie: I've updated my query to answer your question #2. I'm working on an answer to #3.

Comment: +1 Because now the question is a good one.  Sample data.  Sample code.  I'll cut you some slack on the expected results...

Comment: @Zach Please don't mix answers into your question.  This becomes very confusing.  If you feel that you can offer a better answer to your own question, then add a new answer to your own question.  This is encouraged, see for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2706/161858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the code from the previous answers such that they are functions that take the same inputs (a univariate time series) and return the same output (a vector of days since the last n-day high):

```
daysSinceHigh1 <- function(x,n) {
    as.vector(n-rollapply(x, n, which.max))
}

daysSinceHigh2 <- function(x, n){
    apply(embed(x, n), 1, which.max)-1
}
```

The second function seems to be the fastest, but they're providing slightly different results:

```
> getSymbols("^GSPC",from='01-01-1900')
[1] "GSPC"
> system.time(x <- daysSinceHigh1(Cl(GSPC), 200))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.42    0.00    0.42 
> system.time(y <- daysSinceHigh2(Cl(GSPC), 200))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.24    0.00    0.24 
> all.equal(x,y)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.005025126"
```

Upon closer inspection, it appears that there are some weird edge cases in the 1st function:

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,6,7,8,5,4,3,2,1)
answer <- c(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,4,4)
x <- daysSinceHigh1(data, 5)
y <- daysSinceHigh2(data, 5)

> x
 [1] 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 4 0 1 2 3 4 4
> y
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 4 4
> answer
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 4 4
> all.equal(x,answer)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.5714286"
> all.equal(y,answer)
[1] TRUE
```

Therefore, it seems like the second function (based off Andrie's code) is better.

Answer (score 5):

This little function returns a list with:

- `high` the index number of high dates
- `recentHigh` the index number of the most recent high day
- `daysSince` the number of days since the last high
- `data` an xts object with only the high days. Useful for plotting.

The code:

```
daysSinceHigh <- function(data, days){
  highs <- days-1+which(apply(embed(data, days), 1, which.max)==1)
  recentHigh <- max(highs)
  daysSince <- nrow(data) - recentHigh
  list(
    highs=highs,
    recentHigh = recentHigh,
    daysSince = daysSince,
    data=data[highs, ])
}
```

The results:

```
daysSinceHigh(Data, 200)$daysSince
[1] 90

plot(Data)
points(daysSinceHigh(Data, 200)$data, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think you could modify this function such that daysSince is also an xts object, the same length of the original series, that counts the number of days since the last high for each point in the series?  I want to compare the speed of your method to the speed of DWin's method.

Comment: @Zach Since you have already allocated the best answer, even before I posted my answer, and after that changed the question, I'll leave that as an exercise to the interested reader.

Comment: I edited my main question with the results of efforts by an interested reader. =)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your revised question:

```
require(zoo)
x <- sample(300:500, 1000, replace=TRUE)
str(rollapply(x, 200, function(x) which.max(x)))
# int [1:801] 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 ...
 plot(x)
 plot(200:1000, rollapply(x, 200, function(x) 200-which.max(x)))
```

So for the xts series:

```
plot( rollapply(coredata(Data), 200, function(x) 200-which.max(x)))
```

[image]
You obviously cannot merge anything back to the first 200 dates unless you apply a looser definition of rolling maximum. (In another SO session involving "shifty" data I showed how to use embed to pad the "trailing" periods: [Data transformation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225721/data-transformation-in-r/7225936#7225936) but I don't know if you want to construct matrices that are 200 times as large as your input data.)