# How to calculate days since moving average crossover?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to determine the number of days that have passed since the beginning of a trend, e.g. when price has moved above the 200 day moving average (SMA).  For example:

```
require(quantmod)
ticker <- "QQQ"
x <-getSymbols(ticker, auto.assign = FALSE)
sma <- SMA(Ad(x), 200)
```

I'm trying to return a variable that ranges from 0 (first day crossing over the 200 day SMA) to X or -X, depending on whether price is trending above the SMA or below.

Can it be done without a for loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate periods since 200-period high of a stock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354368/how-to-calculate-periods-since-200-period-high-of-a-stock)

Comment: Hi Andrie, it is similar to your post about the 200-d high, but different because I'm trying to calculate the days since price crosses the 200d moving average.

Answer (score 4):

This function will return the number of days since the Adjusted price crossed its moving average (zero on the day it crosses).  The number of days will be a negative number if the current price is below the MA, and will be positive if the current price is above the MA.

`x` is an xts object with an `Adjusted` column, and `n` is the `n` to use for the `SMA`

```
DaysSinceMACross <- function(x, n) {
  prem <- Ad(x) - SMA(Ad(x), n) 
  prem[seq_len(n)] <- 0        
  x$grp <- cumsum(c(0, diff(prem > 0, na.pad=FALSE)) != 0)
  x$sign <- sign(prem)
  x$days <- ave(prem, x$grp, FUN=function(xx) 0:(NROW(xx) - 1))
  x$days * x$sign 
}

x <-getSymbols(ticker, src='yahoo', to='2012-10-22', auto.assign = FALSE)

R> tail(DaysSinceMACross(x, 10))
#           days
#2012-10-15   -5
#2012-10-16    0
#2012-10-17    1
#2012-10-18    0
#2012-10-19   -1
#2012-10-22   -2
```